# Save Several Images to a Jagged Array

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, emgucv, jagged-arrays

I am new to C# so please forgive me if the answer to my question is very easy.

My goal is to capture and store from my camera 10 frames so i can do some post prossesing. I am using a Gige Basler scout monochrome camera.
I know how to acquire the 10 images with a while loop.

So my question is how to save in each iteration of the while loop each image into the same jagged array?

My goal is to save the 10 images into one single 3D jagged array. I declare the jagged array as:

`UInt16[][,] jaggedArray = new UInt16[10][,];`

The camera give the the image into a bitmap format (m_bitmap).

Using Emgu i can convert the bitmat to image (Not sure if i have to do this):

```
Image<Gray, UInt16> IMA = new Image<Gray, UInt16>(m_bitmap);
```

What i want to do is that in each iteration i can save the acquired image in the jagged array:

```
itteration 1 :>>      jaggedArray[0] = 1st Image

itteration 2 :>>      jaggedArray[1] = 2nd Image
```

...

```
itteration 10 :>>      jaggedArray[9] = 10th Image
```

But i don't know how to save the acquired Image or Bitmap inside the jagged array (jaggedArray[i] = ???????????).

In what i have to convert my image or Bitmap to be able to store it inside the jagged array?

Please if you know any better approach to this problem feel free to tell me that.

The captured images have size of (1280,960).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're trying to store the entire image with each loop. Because the Emgu Images are a specific class, not just an array, you can have an array of ten Emgu images.

```
Image<Gray, UINT16>[] rawCaptures = new Image<Gray, UINT16>[10];
// some other code...
while(cameraIsRunning && iWantMoreImages)
{
    // more code here...
    Image<Gray, UInt16> IMA = new Image<Gray, UInt16>(m_bitmap);
    rawCaptures[indexOfCapture] = IMA;
}
```

Comment: That you very much for your answer!  I appreciate your assistant! Also sorry but i cannot give you a score yet as i am not level 15 :( Anyway thank you very much!!